# Entity Framework lazy loading stops working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

Working Code First, I have a class named "Doc" that contains these lines:

```
public class Doc
{
public int DocID { get; set; }
...
[Required]
public int? ProjectID { get; set; }
public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
...
// new properties added here
}

public class Project
{
public int ProjectID { get; set; }
....
}
```

Fetching a Doc row, e.g., via

```
Doc toSubmit = context.Docs.Find(savedDocID);
string projectName = toSubmit.Project.Name; // This statement now fails
```

has worked fine for years. Do the .Find and the virtual Project property gets filled. The second line correctly places the Project's Name in the projectName.

Now I've added more properties at the end of the Doc record and the .Find no longer fills the virtual Project property - it remains null. It fills everything else, including the ProjectID property. I haven't moved anything that was there. I haven't renamed anything that was there. The Project class hasn't changed.

I can't figure out what I broke.

Comment: `Find` never triggers lazy loading. It must always be something afterwards. You probably changed more code than you tell here. At any rate, what you show isn't enough to diagnose this. We need more context of before and after your code changes.

Comment: Please show all the code for the Doc and Project classes.

Comment: Thank you for your questions. Rather than including big slabs of code, I've edited my question to include what I think is relevant to this problem. Again, I've got code that has worked fine for years and is unchanged. And I've changed the class definition by adding properties at the end. ProjectID and Project are still adjacent near the beginning of the Doc class. I know I'm uttering the fateful words, "But I didn't change anything!"

Comment: So it should work again when you remove the new properties. If so, I'm *very* curious what these new properties look like. You may have run into some outlandish bug in EF (EF 6, I assume).

Comment: Gert Arnold. Yes, it does work fine when the new - and completely vanilla -  properties are removed. Go figure!

Comment: Well, not *that* vanilla apparently. Looks like one of them breaks the conditions under which EF will create lazy-loading proxies.